# Asp.net core web-api http action based authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to add two policies to asp.net core api.

1. ReadOnly - only allow get calls
2. AppUser - allow get,put,post,delete

//// policies are in appsettings json

```
Policies.json
{
    "name": "ReadOnly"
    "ids":["user1", "user2"],
}
,
{
    "name": "AppUser"
    "ids":["user3", "user4"]
}
```

//// requirement

```
public class IdRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Ids { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public IdRequirement(string name, List<string> ids)
    {
        Name = name;
        Ids = ids;
    }
}
```

//// handler

```
public class IdHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IdRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IdRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            string currentUserid = GetId(context.User);

            if (requirement.Ids != null && requirement.Ids.Any(x => x == currentUserid))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

//// in services

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var reqList = configuration.GetSection("Policies").Get<List<IdRequirement>>();

    //// app users must have readonly access by default. ReadOnly is the default policy.
    //// not sure this is the correct way?
    
    var appUserReq = reqList.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("AppUser", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    var readOnlyReq = reqList.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("ReadOnly", StringComparison.Ordinal));

    readOnlyReq.Ids = readOnlyReq.Ids.Union(appUserReq.ids).ToList();

    reqList.ForEach(requirement =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(requirement.Name, policy =>
        {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.Requirements.Add(requirement);

        });
    });
});
```

//// in configure

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization("ReadOnly");
});
```

//// controller

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    // GET: userid
    [HttpGet("testget")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "AppUser")]
    [HttpPost("testpost")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostSomething()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If I call testget, it will only authorize readonly requirement. Which is correct for me.

If I call testpost, it will first authorize appuser requirement, then again call readonly requirement.

I don't want to trigger readonly requirement when using [Authorize(Policy = "AppUser")]

1. Am I missing here or misuse concept?
2. Is this default behavior?

I referred this article
https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally using help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536509/how-to-declaritively-specify-authorization-policy-based-on-http-verb-and-other-a/66574006#66574006), I achieved like below. Make sure that you do not need add Authorize attribute anymore in controllers. And can modify `RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods` if you want any custom setting for particular controller.

```
var mutatingHttpMethods = new HashSet<HttpMethod>()
{
    HttpMethod.Post,
    HttpMethod.Put,
    HttpMethod.Delete
};

var getHttpMethods = new HashSet<HttpMethod>()
{
    HttpMethod.Get
};

endpoints
    .MapControllers()
    .RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods(httpMethods => httpMethods.Any(httpMethod => getHttpMethods.Contains(httpMethod)), "ReadOnly")
    .RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods(httpMethods => httpMethods.Any(httpMethod => mutatingHttpMethods.Contains(httpMethod)), "AppUser");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. When putting `[Authorize(Policy = "AppUser")]` on an action, it will authenticate through this policy `AppUser` first. If not succeed, it will redirect to `AccessDeniedPath`. At this time, it will go through the endpoint, and `RequireAuthorization` as a global authorization in the endpoint will be triggered again. If you do not configure the `AccessDeniedPath`, it will return 404.

Comment: my problem is even AppUser policy is succeeded, read only requirement also triggered after. my point is no need to do that right?

Comment: Yes, it will authenticate AppUser first, then authenticate ReadOnly.

Comment: So calling another policy even previous policy succeeded is not overhead?

Comment: No, this overhead is little and do not significantly affect the operating efficiency