# How to declaritively specify authorization policy based on HTTP verb and other attributes in ASP.Net Core (WebAPI)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization

I've got a couple of authorization polcies registered:

```cs
ConfigureServices()
{
    services.AddAuthorization(authorisationOptions =>
    {
        authorisationOptions.AddPolicy(StandardAuthorizationPolicy.Name, StandardAuthorizationPolicy.Value);
        authorisationOptions.AddPolicy(MutatingActionAuthorizationPolicy.Name, MutatingActionAuthorizationPolicy.Value);
    }); 
}
```

& then I set a default authorization policy across all endpoints:

```cs
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints
            .MapControllers()
            .RequireAuthorization(StandardAuthorizationPolicy.Name); // Declaratively require the standard authorization policy on all controller endpoints
    });
}
```

On the endpoints where I want to specify the mutating policy, I currently do the following:

```cs
[HttpPut]
[Authorize(MutatingActionAuthorizationPolicy.Name)] // Because 'PUT'. NOT DECLARATIVE! :-(
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdateOverride(SourceOverride sourceOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // ..
}
```

What I really want is a bit more control to declaritively apply the mutating policy based on the HttpVerb (i.e. POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE).

Any idea on how to achieve that? Bonus points for allowing me to use other attributes on the controller method/class, not just `[HttpPost]` etc.

NB: I've seen solutions floating around that involve casting the content (and seem to revolve around a single access policy). I'd really rather stick with multiple access policies.

If I get stuck, I might end up writing a convention test for it.

Comment: I think the control should be applied when you develop it, not justify it after starting the application. Because the AuthorizeAttribute is loaded when the application is starting, and  the AuthorizationHandler can not get the HttpContext, so it could not know the Httpverbs when the client requests the server.

Comment: This is the definition of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: What's the Y problem in this case please @Andy?

Comment: There are no capabilities built in to ASP.NET Core framework because no one would ever restrict interaction based on verb. You restrict based on claims (such as roles) of the *user* invoking the endpoint and the data they are accessing. Verbs are a way to define the action of an endpoint. They were never meant to be used in this way. Is it possible? Absolutely.Anything is possible. But just because it's possible, doesn't mean it should be done. It's unorthodox, which is why your question sat long enough to put a bounty on it with no attempts to answer it. Your Y is tying authorization to verb.

Comment: @Andy The two access policies (StandardAuthorizationPolicy & MutatingActionAuthorizationPolicy) already check things such as "Is the user authenticated" and "Do they have the appropriate claims" (in our case we translate assigned roles into claims).

What I'm trying to do is prevent silly mistakes where someone has forgotten to apply a policy (and the default policy has been used). Seems like a convention test might be the way to go.

Comment: OK then, why tie it to a verb?

Comment: See edited comment directly above.

Comment: You could make an `IActionFilter` which is is registerd as global filter. Checks if the current action method has the `PutAttribute`, does validate against the `IAuthoirzationService` and sets a new ChallengeResult() in case. Just on top of my head, not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a custom RequireAuthorization extension that takes HTTP verb filtering function as an argument and checks each endpoint metadata for HttpMethodAttribute

```cs
public static class AuthorizationEndpointConventionBuilderExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds authorization policies with the specified <see cref="IAuthorizeData"/> to the endpoint(s) filtered by supplied filter function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">The endpoint convention builder.</param>
        /// <param name="filterOnHttpMethods">Filters http methods that we applying specific policies to</param>
        /// <param name="authorizeData">
        /// A collection of <paramref name="authorizeData"/>. If empty, the default authorization policy will be used.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>The original convention builder parameter.</returns>
        public static TBuilder RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, Func<IEnumerable<HttpMethod>, bool> filterOnHttpMethods, params IAuthorizeData[] authorizeData)
            where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            if (authorizeData == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authorizeData));
            }

            if (authorizeData.Length == 0)
            {
                authorizeData = new IAuthorizeData[] { new AuthorizeAttribute(), };
            }

            builder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
            {
                var appliedHttpMethodAttributes = endpointBuilder.Metadata
                .Where(x => x is HttpMethodAttribute)
                .Cast<HttpMethodAttribute>();

                if (appliedHttpMethodAttributes.Any(x => filterOnHttpMethods(x.HttpMethods
                                              .Select(method => new HttpMethod(method)))))
                {
                    foreach (var data in authorizeData)
                    {
                        endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            return builder;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds authorization policies with the specified names to the endpoint(s) for filtered endpoints that return for filterOnHttpMethod
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">The endpoint convention builder.</param>
        /// <param name="filterOnHttpMethods">Filters http methods that we applying specific policies to</param>
        /// <param name="policyNames">A collection of policy names. If empty, the default authorization policy will be used.</param>
        /// <returns>The original convention builder parameter.</returns>
        public static TBuilder RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, Func<IEnumerable<HttpMethod>, bool> filterOnHttpMethods, params string[] policyNames)
        where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            if (policyNames == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(policyNames));
            }

            return builder.RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods(filterOnHttpMethods, policyNames.Select(n => new AuthorizeAttribute(n)).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

And then use this extension next to the original one:

```cs
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            var mutatingHttpMethods = new HashSet<HttpMethod>()
            {
                HttpMethod.Post,
                HttpMethod.Put,
                HttpMethod.Delete
            };

            endpoints
                .MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization(StandardAuthorizationPolicy.Name)
                .RequireAuthorizationForHttpMethods(httpMethods => 
                 httpMethods.Any(httpMethod => mutatingHttpMethods.Contains(httpMethod)), 
                 MutatingActionAuthorizationPolicy.Name);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Eugene. 

I think on further reflection Andy was right, this was an XY problem (the *real* problem I wanted to solve was "How can I enforce every controller action has an authorization policy applied to it?") - a convention test is probably a better approach for that.